# Android sent string from one activity to another not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to ask something that maybe simple, but I still can't find the problem.

I sent a string from one activity to another activity, but its show nothing.
I already checked it several times, and I think there's nothing wrong with my code.

**Here's My first java code ( FoodFilter.class)**

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.filter_type))
                    .getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_list))
                    .getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_name))
                    .getText().toString();

            // Starting single contact activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    FoodFilterDetail.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
            in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
```

**This is the FoodFilterDetail.class**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.foods_filterdetail);

    TextView txtProduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.filterItemList);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    // getting attached intent data
    String product = i.getStringExtra("TAG_NAME");
    // displaying selected product name
    txtProduct.setText(product);

}
```

**Here's my xml**

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dip" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/filterItemList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="Sort By"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I get the data on `FoodFilter.class` from json parse and it works fine. I can show all the data on `ListView`, but when I send the string to `FoodFilterDetail.class` it show nothing and there's no error or warning in my code.

Is there anyone can help me to fix this? I've been searching the problem for whole day.

Thanks Before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create one variable in FoodFilter.java

```
public static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
```

use this 
in  FoodFilter.java

```
in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
```

and in FoodFilterDetail.java

```
String product = i.getStringExtra(FoodFilter.TAG_NAME);
```

Do the same for all other variable

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know why my code is no t working, because I use it for another class and it works perfectly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

use `i.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);` instead of `i.getStringExtra("TAG_NAME");`

Comment: @Matthew: Use the same as in the `FoodFilter` class.

Comment: have you declared TAG_NAME in your other activity decalare it here also and please accept my answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are defining `TAG_NAME` like this in the first activity:

```
public static final String TAG_NAME = "some_random_key";
```

Then you are setting it as the key for `Intent` like this:

```
in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
```

And in the second activity you are trying to access it like this:

```
String product = i.getStringExtra("TAG_NAME");
```

Which will not work since the key is not `"TAG_NAME"` but `"some_random_key"`. So to access it in the second activity you need to define `TAG_NAME` in the second activity as well just like you did in the first activity:

```
public static final String TAG_NAME = "some_random_key";
```

And then access the string like:

```
String product = i.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
```